# I wanna achieve pagination on a visualforce page via custom controller class

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, pagination

I want to achieve pagination on a visualforce page with the help of custom controller,right now my code is not working as expected.
Can anyone please help me in what I am doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSearchClass">
<apex:form >
    <apex:inputText value="{!searchVariable}" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search" reRender="rr"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="rr">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accObj}" var="b"  >
            <apex:column value="{!b.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!b.Phone}" />
            <apex:column value="{!b.AccountNumber}" />        
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search" reRender="rr"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="First Page" rerender="rr" action="{!FirstPage}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Previous" rerender="rr" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!prev}"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Next" rerender="rr" action="{!next}" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Custom controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountSearchClass {
public String searchVariable { get; set; }
public Integer OffsetSize=0;
public Integer LimitSize=5;
public Integer Totalrec=0;
private String temp;
public List <Account> accObj {get; set;}
public void search() {
    temp = 'Select id ,Name,AccountNumber,Phone from Account WHERE Name Like \'%'+searchVariable+'%\' OR Phone Like \'%'+searchVariable+'%\' ';
    accObj = database.query(temp);
    Totalrec=accObj.size();
}
public void FirstPage()
{
    OffsetSize = 0;
}
public void previous()
{
    OffsetSize =  LimitSize-OffsetSize;
}
public void next()
{
    OffsetSize = OffsetSize + LimitSize;
}
public boolean getprev()
{
    if(OffsetSize == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public boolean getnxt()
{
    if((OffsetSize + LimitSize) > Totalrec)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: the next button is not showing up when i preview the page

Comment: Also all the records are getting displayed at the first page only.

Comment: yes that's because you didn't use offset and limit in your query.  I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a lot of missing things in your code

1. Add `search();` at the end of each of these 3 methods : `FirstPage(), Next(), Previous()`
2. Your temp query is missing `OFFSET` AND `LIMIT`at the end of the query. Add it correctly using the variables OffsetSize and LimitSize (LIMIT LimitSize OFFSET OffsetSize)
3. All your apex:command buttons should be within the pageblock!  So, end your `<apex:pageblock>` after the commandbuttons.

Follow the Example in this link.

https://sfdcfanboy.wordpress.com/2016/06/14/visualforce-pagination-with-dynamic-search/

Update your code accordingly.  It should work.

Comment: that's ok, No problem!